# In Lion's new Mail.app, is it possible to change the font size of the mailbox list?

Tags: mail.app, font

I have a small screen and MANY email mailboxes. I'd like to make the side panel font size smaller, but I can't find an option for it. Is there one?

(I can change the font size in messages and in the message list--that's not what I'm talking about.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3191375?start=0&tstart=0) says System Preferences -> General controls it.

Comment: Thanks. I don't like the answer (gives you very little control!) but it is something at least...

Answer (score 0):

this was already answered, but you can go to Mail.app > Preferences > Fonts and Colors > Message List font to change this.

Comment: No, you can't.  That does not have any impact at all on the sidebar font size, which is what is being asked about here.